Is the number $(-2)^\frac{3}{5}$ is a complex number?
If I try it in python VS in calculator
the calculator returns an answer of -1.5517
on the other hand,  I wrote a short Python script it returns a complex number (see the 1st image attached)

Why such difference and who is right?
P.S
In my humble opinion $(-2)^{(\frac{3}{5})}$ is not complex since has one simple solution (see the 2nd image attached):

Am I missing something and python does right?

Both are right. They are just choosing different fifth roots based on their internal algorithms.

Documentation of the Python pow function says " For a negative base of type int or float and a non-integral exponent, a complex result is delivered.". I'm guessing it probably returns the one with the smallest angle.

What's the definition $a^r$ when $a$ is negative and $r$ is rational.  Every number (except $0$) has $5$ fifth roots.  Which one are you defining to be "the" value of $(-2)^{\frac 35}$.

You can simply check, for both of your values $a_{1,2}$, whether $a_i^{5/3}=-2.

$(-2)^{\frac{1}{5}}$ has five values by De Moivre's theorem. One is real, the others occur in complex conjugate pairs. Raising each of these to the power 3 gives five different numbers, each of them a solution to $z^{\frac{5}{3}}=-2$.
So, yes $(-2)^{\frac{3}{5}}$ can be a real number if we choose the principal root.
There are complex roots as well.
A lot of programming languages (Wolfram included) tends to choose a complex root with a positive real part when asked for the value of an expression such as this.

I think the principal root $z^{1/5}$ returns a real number only when $z>0$. For $-2$, the principal root would be computed by considering $-2=2\mathrm{e}^{\pi \mathrm{i}}$.

@Gary thanks. I know from coding in Wolfram language that this is a common issue I have to think carefully about how to avoid... I'm not confident in the actual definition of principal root either.

@RedFive Thank you
Just to make sure

When the calculator returns an answer of -1.5157 this belongs to what you have described as the one out of 5 possible answers which is a real number (meaning that its imaginary part =0)
Right?
The rest of the answers are complex but their abs value is also equal to  -1.5157
according to:  abs = sqrt(real^2+imaginary^2)
Right?
You actually say that there are 4 such "abs" while each of them is equal to  -1.5157
but they differ one from another due to different values for the real and the imaginary parts that they consist of.
Right?


@Igor yes, that is given by De Moivre's theorem. There are a lot of really nice patterns in these types of problem, but they can be a pain when you are working in a coding environment and just want the real values.

@RedFive
And the number of 5 comes from the 1/5 you have mentioned? Or it is always five?

$z^n=z_{0}$ where n is an integer will have n solutions. If $z_{0}$ is real, then one of the solutions will be real (or two if n is even) and the rest will occur in complex conjugate pairs. The solutions will be equally spaced around a circle with centre (0,0).

Some light reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers
